# Javascript - transforming an object of array list to new formated one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mapping

I'm trying to transform an object contain array to another one with javascript. Below is an example of the object field and what the formatted one should look like.

```
let Fields = {
  GAME: [
    { code: '{{PES}}', title: { en: "playPES"} },
    { code: '{{FIFA}}', title: { en: "playFIFA " } },
  ]
};
```

I need The new Fields to looks like this

```
let newFields = {
name: 'GAME', 
tags:[
   { name: 'playPES', value: "{{PES}}" },
   { name: 'playFIFA', value: "{{FIFA}}" }
      ]},
```

One contributor suggested me a method like this but i think something need to modify in it but couldn't figure it out.

```
export const transform = (fields) => ({
  tags: Object .entries (fields) .map (([name, innerFields]) => ({
    name,
    tags: innerFields.map(({code, title: title: {en})=>({name: en, value: code}))
  }))
});
```

// newFields= transform(Fields)

I'm new working with javascript so any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Not really enough known here. Are you importing and calling `transform(Fields)` anywhere? Any errors thrown? What does happen?

Comment: yes i call it newFields= transform(Fields) , it doenst transform fields to tht format , something is worng in the function

Comment: Ok...that's a bit better explanation than just saying it's not working. Always try to including any debugging details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const transform = (o) => {
    return Object.entries(o).map((e)=>({
        name: e[0],
        tags: e[1].map((k)=>({name: (k.title)?k.title.en:undefined, value: k.code}))
    }))[0]
}

console.log(transform({
  GAME: [
    { code: '{{PES}}', title: { en: "playPES"} },
    { code: '{{FIFA}}', title: { en: "playFIFA " } },
  ]
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is more readable, but not easier... If you want the result as object you need to use reduce, because when you do this

```
Object.keys(Fields)
```

Your object transform to array, but reduce can change array to object back.

```js
let Fields = {
  GAME: [
    { code: '{{PES}}', title: { en: "playPES"} },
    { code: '{{FIFA}}', title: { en: "playFIFA " } },
  ]
};

const result = Object.keys(Fields).reduce((acc, rec) => {
    return {
      name: rec,  
      tags: Fields[rec].map(el => {
        return {
          name: el.title.en,
          value: el.code
        }
    })
    }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the entries method you posted:

```
let Fields = {
  GAME: [
    { code: '{{PES}}', title: { en: "playPES"} },
    { code: '{{FIFA}}', title: { en: "playFIFA " } },
  ]
};

// 1. Obtain keys and values from first object
Fields = Object.entries(oldFields);

// 2. Create new object
const newFields = {};

// 3. Create the name key value pair from new Fields array
newFields.name = Fields[0][0];

// 4. Create the tags key value pair by mapping the subarray in the new Fields array
newFields.tags = Fields[0][1].map(entry => ({ name: entry.title.en, value: entry.code }));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries(Fields)` will return this:

```
[
  "GAME",
  [TagsArray]
]
```

And `Object.entries(Fields).map` will be mapping this values.

The first map, will receive only `GAME`, and not an array.

Change the code to something like this:

```
export const transform = (Fields) => {
  const [name, tags] = Object.entries(Fields);

  return {
    name,
    tags: tags.map(({ code, title }) => ({
      name: title.en,
      value: code
    }))
  }
}
```

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Fields = {
    GAME: [
      { code: '{{PES}}', title: { en: "playPES"} },
      { code: '{{FIFA}}', title: { en: "playFIFA " } },
    ]
  };
  let newFields = {
    name: 'GAME', 
        tags:[
            { name: 'playPES', value: "{{PES}}" },
            { name: 'playFIFA', value: "{{FIFA}}" }
        ]
    }
  let answer = {
    name: "Game",
        tags: [

        ]
  }
  Fields.GAME.map(i => {
      var JSON = {
        "name": i.title.en,
        "value": i.code
      }
      answer.tags.push(JSON);
  });
  console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let Fields = {
    GAME: [
      { code: '{{PES}}', title: { en: "playPES"} },
      { code: '{{FIFA}}', title: { en: "playFIFA " } },
    ]
};

const transform = (fields) => ({
    tags: Object .entries (fields) .map (([name, innerFields]) => ({
      name,
      tags: innerFields.map(({code, title: title,en})=>({name: title.en, value: code}))
    }))
  });
//check required output in console
console.log(transform(Fields));
```